# Randomize cfoutput

Tags: coldfusion

The following code changes the body BG dependent on if the /home url is active else use a different BG. We have the pageID = 206 containing the /home BG image and pageID = 207 containing the else BG image. We currently have it setup this way so the client can go into the CMS and change the BG image without an issue.

However, the client would like the ability to add additional backgrounds and have them randomize. In theory I would add a page to the CMS and include the pageID and add randomize. I'm familiar with ColdFusion but this is a little over my head. Any input or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="HOME_BG">
  <cfoutput>
<cfset includeID = '206'><cfinclude emplate='/PageInclude/PageInclude.cfm'/>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset BG1 = getToken(HOME_BG,3, """") >

<cfsavecontent variable="COMM_BG">
  <cfoutput>
<cfset includeID = '207'><cfinclude template='/PageInclude/PageInclude.cfm'/>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>  
<cfset BG2 = getToken(COMM_BG,3, """") >

<body onload="checkCookie()" style="background-image: url(<cfoutput><cfif fpath EQ "home">#BG1#<cfelse>#BG2#</cfif></cfoutput>);">
```

I was looking for the ability to randomize between two different < cfset > but didn't find much luck.

Solution using an array and randrange

```
<cfset bgHomeIDArray = ArrayNew(1)>     <!--- Create the array --->
<cfset ArrayAppend(bgHomeIDArray, 214)>     <!--- Adds an array value --->
<cfset ArrayAppend(bgHomeIDArray, 215)>     <!--- Adds an array value --->
<cfsavecontent variable="HOME_BG">
  <cfoutput>
<cfset includeID = bgHomeIDArray[randRange(1, len(bgHomeIDArray))]>  <cfinclude template='/PageInclude/PageInclude.cfm'/>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset BG1 = getToken(HOME_BG,3, """") >


<cfset bgCommIDArray = ArrayNew(1)>     <!--- Create the array --->
<cfset ArrayAppend(bgCommIDArray, 216)>     <!--- Adds an array value --->
<cfset ArrayAppend(bgCommIDArray, 217)>     <!--- Adds an array value --->
<cfsavecontent variable="COMM_BG">
  <cfoutput>
<cfset includeID = bgCommIDArray[randRange(1, len(bgCommIDArray))]><cfinclude template='/PageInclude/PageInclude.cfm'/>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset BG2 = getToken(COMM_BG,3, """") >

<body onLoad="checkCookie()" style="background-image: url(<cfoutput><cfif fpath EQ "home">#BG1#<cfelse>#BG2#</cfif></cfoutput>?03202014);">
```

Comment: Look at using a structure or array with the includeID's and using [RandRange](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/RandRange)

Comment: I believe this might be a possible solution if you have any suggestions. The randRange are the pageID's.

"<cfset homeBG = randRange(214,215)
<cfsavecontent variable="HOME_BG">
  <cfoutput>
<cfset includeID = #homeBG#><cfinclude template='/PageInclude/PageInclude.cfm'/>
  </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset BG1 = getToken(HOME_BG,3, """") >"

Comment: that would work. you shouldn't need the `cfoutput` around your include though.